# Nginx & Passenger - failed (11: Resource temporarily unavailable) while connecting to upstream

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, ruby-on-rails, phusion-passenger, tuning

I have an Nginx and Passenger setup that is proving problematic.

At relatively low loads the server seems to get backed up and start churning results like this into the error.log:

```
connect() to unix:/passenger_helper_server failed 
(11: Resource temporarily unavailable) while connecting to upstream
```

My passenger setup is:

```
passenger_min_instances 2;
passenger_pool_idle_time 1200;
passenger_max_pool_size 20;
```

I have done some digging, and it looks like the CPU gets pegged. Memory usage seems fine passenger_memory_stats shows at most about 700MB being used, but CPU approaches 100%.

is this enough to cause this type of error?

Should i bring the pool size down?
Are there other configuration settings I should be looking at?

Any help appreciated

Other pertinent information:

- Amazon EC2 Small Instance
- Ubuntu 10.10
- Nginx (latest stable)
- Passenger (latest stable)
- Rails 3.0.4

Comment: Hi, I've exactly the same problem, with some traffic I got that error

I'm googling around and here there is a guy with that problem, nginx+php: http://www.devcomments.com/11-Resource-temporarily-unavailable-while-connecting-to-upstream-at39723.htm


My config:
nginx/0.6.35 + Phusion Passenger 2.2.10

  passenger_max_pool_size 6;
  passenger_pool_idle_time 3600;

Please let me know if you find a solution, I'll do the same.

Thank you

Comment: Same problem here. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: Never did find the answer, but decreasing the passenger pool helped immensely.

Comment: what did you decrease it to?

Comment: @jdkealy can't recall from memory, but I think I started at about 5 and worked my way back up until I saw the error again.

Answer (score 1):

With the CPU approaching 100% and looking at the specs of the EC2 small instance, it sounds to me like your machine is swapping. Have a look at the output of `free -m` while you boot up the server and then watch it when you do some load testing.

From the docs of Phusion Passenger

> A larger number results in higher memory usage, but improves the ability to handle concurrent HTTP requests.

Do you really need to handle a lot of concurrent requests? If so, you should probably invest in a larger EC2 instance and then turn up your `passenger_max_pool_size`. It doubt that you will need more than the default of 6 that passenger provides with that little machine.